# Getting Data from Values in the Registry [C#]

Tags: c#, registry

My program contains quite a few values in the registry and getting the names of these values is not problematic at all; the real problem is getting the data from these particular values.

Here is a segment of my code. Assume "paths.mainKey" is "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node". Also assume that "paths.subKey" is "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Razer Chroma SDK" (obviously not my key, just using it as an example).

```
private void ReadRegistry()
{
    string[] allSubKeys = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(paths.mainKey).GetSubKeyNames();
    if (allSubKeys.Contains("Razer Chroma SDK"))
    {
        string[] allDayPolicies = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(paths.subKey).GetValueNames();
        foreach (string value in allDayPolicies)
        {
            //Read data from the values?
        }
    }
}
```

[This is a visual representation of what I'm trying to get from the Registry.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCncc.png)

Anyone know how to obtain this data?

Comment: How is getting those values a problem? Have you used the `GetValue()` method?

Comment: You deleted your question regarding the shutdown on your pc versus laptop. I was about to suggest to you a different way to determine the time - try this: `DateTime.ParseExact(TIME_START_TIME, "H tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay`

Comment: @Enigmativity I appreciate the suggestion, however, I figured out the solution to my problem; when I was converting the times from the registry to military time, I did not add a case for when the time was "12 AM". The way my code worked, this meant that it became 12 PM instead, making the restart block of code not execute because the conditions were not met.

Comment: @MTS11648 - Ah, so my above code would have solved the issue too. Good stuff. You shouldn't have deleted your question if you found the answer - you should have answered your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GetValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdf576x1(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void ReadRegistry()
{
    string[] allSubKeys = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(paths.mainKey).GetSubKeyNames();
    if (allSubKeys.Contains("Razer Chroma SDK"))
    {
        var subKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(paths.subKey);
        string[] allDayPolicies = subKey.GetValueNames();
        foreach (string name in allDayPolicies)
        {
            var value = subKey.GetValue(name);
            // do something with value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Had no idea it was that easy. Thanks.